# How to make changes to some branch, corresponding to some branch in git?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

Suppose I have two branches in git, one is A and other is B, A is the main branch on which main development happens and B is the branch created by me to do some tasks, but i am required to pull the changes done to main branch so Branch B is updated with the other changes, how can i reflect changes in my branch B corresponding to A.

I have explored it through resources but still have confusion regarding the concept.